# Print a variable as part of a multiline string?

Tags: scala

```
val name = "Cory"
"""
  |Hi! My name is " + name + " how are you?
""".stripMargin
```

The portion `+ name +` doesn't get interpreted as code, but just as text. How can I print the value of a variable inside a multiline string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're on 2.10 or later, you can use string interpolation:

```
scala> s"""
     |   |Hi! My name is $name how are you?
     | """.stripMargin
res0: String = 
"
Hi! My name is Cory how are you?
"
```

For 2.9 or earlier you're stuck with something like this:

```
scala> ("""
     |   |Hi! My name is """ + name + """ how are you?
     | """).stripMargin
res1: String = 
"
Hi! My name is Cory how are you?
"
```

Note that there are [several flavors of string interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) in Scala—`s"..."` is the simplest.